# algebraic numbers and algebraic integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic number. Obviously, one can find $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\beta$ an algebraic integer such that $\alpha=\frac{\beta}d$. But can one choose $d$ and $\beta$ such that for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak M$ of $O_\alpha$, the ring of intgers of $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, such that $v_{\mathfrak M}(d)>0$, one has $v_{\mathfrak M}(\beta)=0$?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: If you want $d\in\mathbb N$, then this is virtually never true. For example, take $\alpha = \frac 1{\sqrt 2} = \frac{\sqrt 2}2$ and let $\mathfrak m = (\sqrt 2)$. If $d\in\mathbb N$, then $v_{\mathfrak m}(d)$ must be even, while $v_{\mathfrak m}(\sqrt 2) = 1$ is odd. So there's no way of expressing $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ in the desired form.

Comment: If you just assume that $d$ is an algebraic integer, then this is still false, since $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ might not be a PID. So it's not always possible to write an element $\alpha$ is a ratio of coprime integers.